# Extract Text Plugin 'loader is used without the corresponding plugin' - React, Sass, Webpack

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack, extract-text-plugin

I'm trying to get SASS compilation running on my React + Webpack project and keep running into this error:

```
Module build failed: Error: "extract-text-webpack-plugin" loader is used without the corresponding plugin
```

Followed the guidelines from this tutorial: [Link](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/05/15/howto-setup-webpack-on-es6-react-application-with-sass.html)

Here is my webpack.config.js

Any suggestions?

```
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/client.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      },
      {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('dist/styles/main.css', {
        allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your `NODE_ENV` is not `production`, you don't include any plugins.

```
plugins: debug ? [] : [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('dist/styles/main.css', {
    allChunks: true
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
],
```

So when `debug` is true, you'll have

```
plugins: []
```

But you're still using it in the `.scss` loader.

To solve it, you can add it to these plugins as well (so you don't have the production plugins like `UglifyJsPlugin`):

```
plugins: debug
  ? [
      new ExtractTextPlugin("dist/styles/main.css", {
        allChunks: true
      })
    ]
  : [
      new ExtractTextPlugin("dist/styles/main.css", {
        allChunks: true
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false })
    ]
```

Or you don't use the `ExtractTextPlugin` in your `.scss` loader (this won't extract them to a css file in development):

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: debug ? 'css!sass' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
}
```

Comment: @Micahel Jungo - This has fixed it however, my sass is not compiling into the main.css sheet?

Comment: Without `ExtractTextPlugin` it won't create a css file, but it's in your JS bundle. So if you still want it to be extracted, you need to use the plugin in development as well.

Comment: Sorry mate I'm a bit confused... It seems this is all around the debug state. Is it better to remove it? I'm unsure what my webpack.config file should look like to get this running and compiling sass into a single .css sheet?

Comment: Yes if you remove it entirely, you can just always use the same plugins and it will always extract them into a css file. I updated the answer to show the other possibility (adding it to dev plugins as well)

Comment: Removed debug entirely and working! What a mission - many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So I solved this by installing style-loader, css-loader, and sass-loader.

```
npm install style-loader css-loader sass-loader --save-dev
```

Then I used them like this.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader","css-loader!sass-loader"),
 },
```

Comment: I updated the code to your suggestion and no fix sadly :-(

Comment: Just to confirm, are you using webpack 1 or  2 ? Also are you getting the same error ?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I was providing with proper syntax, since it webpack pack 2 it changes a bit. Also I got to work on a project with using style loader and css loader along with extract text I will be updating my answer.

Comment: Can you please show me with you new edits what your full config file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred for me because of incorrect format of parameters - 
refer this -> 
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/207

my code looks like this 
`module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            })
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'css/[name].css', disable: false, allChunks: true })
    ]`